# How can we configure HttpProxy on services.AddAzureClients

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, azure-blob-storage

we have the following code in our  .Net 5.0 aspnetcore startup class

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  services.AddAzureClients(builder =>
  {
 
    // Add a storage account client
    builder.AddBlobServiceClient(storageUrl);
    // Use the environment credential by default
    builder.UseCredential(new EnvironmentCredential());
  });

  services.AddControllers();
}
```

for HttpClient we are able to configure httpproxy using the following code, **but how do we acheive the same for BlobServiceClient ??**

```
  services.AddHttpClient("SampleClient", client =>
                {
                    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://sample.client.url.com");
                })
            .ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(() => new HttpClientHandler
            {
                Proxy = new WebProxy("https://sample.proxy.url.com")
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to pass BlobClientOptions with the appropriate proxy URI specified, into the constructor of BlobServiceClient.

Checkout this [sample code](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/master/sdk/core/Azure.Core/samples/Configuration.md#configuring-a-proxy) which shows how specify a proxy in a HttpClient

The HttpClient can be passed as a parameter when constructing a new HttpClientTransport, which can be set in the Transport property of  [BlobClientOption](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.blobclientoptions?view=azure-dotnet), which can then be passed into the constructor of BlobServiceClient.

Comment: wouldn't setting the environment variables not work ?  the azure SDK specifies that we can set the HTTPS_PROXY, which would be picked by the SDK. and is my assumption wrong that the serviceclients are basically extension methods of the azure SDK ?

Answer (score 0):

```
var blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(_serviceUri, new 
AzureSasCredential(_sasToken), new BlobClientOptions()     
{
     Transport = new HttpClientTransport(new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler 
     {
        Proxy = new WebProxy("proxy-url:port", BypassOnLocal: true),
        UseProxy = true
    }))
});
```