# Azure Blob Storage client library v12 setting proxy

Tags: c#, proxy, azure-blob-storage

I migrate from v11 to v12 and I want to replace :

```
var c = new CloudBlobClient(credentiels, delegatingHandler);
```

to

```
var c = new BlobServiceClient(uri, credentiels);
```

The problem is how to pass that the `delegatingHandler` in v12 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> v12 azure.Storage.Blobs class name is different from v11. v12 has no DelegatingHandler parameter in the constructor.

The DelegatingHandler can change the Proxy property of the HttpClientHandler.

- In such scenario, this instance will be unique to the client. If you don't specify a DelegatingHandler, a singleton HttpClientHandler will be used.
- As previously said, we utilise DelegatingHandler, which has the ability to alter Proxy's properties. First, we'll build a DelegatingHandler implementation for that reason.

**ProxyInjectionHandler.cs**

```
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Hoge {
  public class ProxyInjectionHandler: DelegatingHandler {
    private readonly IWebProxy Proxy;
    private bool FirstCall = true;

    public ProxyInjectionHandler(IWebProxy proxy) {
      this.Proxy = proxy;
    }

    protected override Task <HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) {
      if (FirstCall) {
        var handler = (HttpClientHandler) this.InnerHandler;
        handler.Proxy = this.Proxy;
        handler.UseProxy = true;
        FirstCall = false;
      }
      return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
  }
}
```

Pass this to the client's constructor.

```
var account = CloudStorageAccount.Parse (connectionString);  
var client = new CloudBlobClient (account.BlobEndpoint, account.Credentials, new ProxyInjectionHandler (new WebProxy (new Uri (proxyUrl))));  
var container = client.GetContainerReference ("...");  
await container.CreateIfNotExistsAsync ();
```

**REFERENCES:**

- [Socket exhaustion when using HttpClient in multiple threads](https://www.codenong.com/0acc81a7345df364a35c/)
- [Accessing Azure Storage via HTTP Proxy for v12](https://qiita.com/c-yan/items/0d86259bc3be8304e8b5)

Comment: Hello, thank you for your explanation the question is how to apply this to version v12 :D this is the exact situation I'm asking about.

Comment: @gabida, for proxy setup in v12, see usage of `BlobClientOptions` in this answer, https://stackoverflow.com/a/68997545/122524. Specifically, you'd use your `delegatingHandler` to construct a `HttpClientTransport`.